# How to reset the lap count of stopwatch and run again

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I was designed the below code for a stopwatch. 
All the option is working properly for first time still click on reset button.
But the childAppend of lap didn't work properly. 
Once I clicked reset button,the lap option didn't show when I used

< -- document.getElementById("mainContainer").remove();  -->

if I will not used the above code, it shows the old values in lap didn't remove

```js
var secOne = 0,
  secTwo = 0,
  minOne = 0,
  minTwo = 0,
  hourOne = 0,
  hourTwo = 0;
var t;
var timer_is_on = 0;

function timedCount() {
  document.getElementById("txt").value = (hourTwo + hourOne + ":" + minTwo + minOne + ":" + secTwo + secOne);
  secOne++;
  secMinCount();
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    timedCount();
  }, 1000);
}

function secMinCount() {
  if (secOne == 10) {
    secTwo++;
    secOne = 0;
    if (secTwo == 6) {
      minOne++;
      secTwo = 0;
      if (minOne == 10)
        minHourCount();
    }
  }
}

function minHourCount() {
  minTwo++;
  minOne = 0;
  if (minTwo == 6) {
    hourOne++;
    minTwo = 0;
    if (hourOne == 10) {
      hourOne = 0;
      hourTwo++;
    }
  }
}

function startWatch() {
  $('#start').hide();
  $('#stop').show();
  $('#lap').show();
  $('#reset').show();
  startContinue();
}

function stopWatch() {
  $('#stop').hide();
  $('#continue').show();
  clearTimeout(t);
  timer_is_on = 0;
}

function continueWatch() {
  $('#continue').hide();
  $('#stop').show();
  startContinue();
}

function startContinue() {
  if (!timer_is_on) {
    timer_is_on = 1;
    timedCount();
  }
}

function lapWatch() {
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var newText = document.createElement('output');
  newText.type = "output";
  newText.value = hourTwo + hourOne + ":" + minTwo + minOne + ":" + secTwo + secOne;
  newDiv.appendChild(newText);
  mainContainer.appendChild(newDiv);
}

function resetWatch() {
  $('#lap').hide();
  $('#stop').hide();
  $('#continue').hide();
  $('#start').show();
  $('#reset').hide();
  clearTimeout(t);
  timer_is_on = 0;
  secOne = 0, secTwo = 0, minOne = 0, minTwo = 0, hourOne = 0, hourTwo = 0;
  document.getElementById("txt").value = hourTwo + hourOne + ":" + minTwo + minOne + ":" + secTwo + secOne;
  document.getElementById("mainContainer").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Stopwatch</title>
  
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="continueWatch()" id="continue" style="display:none">Continue count!</button>
  <button onclick="startWatch()" id="start">Start count!</button>
  <button onclick="stopWatch()" id="stop" style="display:none">Stop count!</button>
  <button onclick="resetWatch()" id="reset" style="display:none">Reset count!</button>
  <input type="text" id="txt" value="0:00:00">

  <div id="mainContainer">
    <button onclick="lapWatch()" id="lap" style="display:none">Lap count!</button>
  </div>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're removing the whole div and not just the divs inside the div.

Updated Code:

```
function resetWatch() {

  var mainContainer = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
  Array.prototype.slice.call(mainContainer.getElementsByTagName('DIV')).forEach(function(e) {
    e.remove();
  });
  console.dir(mainContainer);

  $('#lap').hide();
  $('#stop').hide();
  $('#continue').hide();
  $('#start').show();
  $('#reset').hide();

  clearTimeout(t);
  timer_is_on = 0;
  secOne = 0, secTwo = 0, minOne = 0, minTwo = 0, hourOne = 0, hourTwo = 0;
  document.getElementById("txt").value = hourTwo + hourOne + ":" + minTwo + minOne + ":" + secTwo + secOne;
};
```

Were loop the main continer for all `divs` with `mainContainer.getElementsByTagName('DIV')` so we don't remove the button and only remove the lap count numbers. Great place to read about [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) which let you loop an array of elements.

Also some great console tools are [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) and [console.dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir).

Also wish to use jQuery try:

```
  $("#mainContainer > div").each(function(v, e) {
    $(e).remove();
  });
```

Not sure if by design but the lap count is one second a head sometimes if this is not desired change:

`newText.value = hourTwo + hourOne + ":" + minTwo + minOne + ":" + secTwo + secOne;`

to `newText.value = document.getElementById('txt').value;`